# merge two json files with common field value in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have two json files that I am generating already with PHP. One, is outputting like the below. *i.e.* /`json1.json`

```
{
   "Zipcode":"22581",
   "City":"",
   "Primary State":"Maryland",
   "Common Field":"49969",
   "County":"Something"
}
```

The second is outputting like below. *i.e*  /`json2.json`

```
{
    "Common Field":"49969",
    "Option 1":"Y",
    "Option 2":"",
    "Option 3":""
}
```

**I would like to find a way to merge them, ideally using PHP so they output as below**:

```
{
    "Zipcode":"22581",
    "City":"",
    "Primary State":"Maryland",
    "Common Field": {
       "Common Field":"49969",
       "Option 1":"Y",
       "Option 2":"",
       "Option 3":""
    },
    "County":"Something"
},
```

**Update,** the below method that two posters recommended is not working: With or without the use of true at the end, this just outputs the json with numbers next to each entry. And does not concatenate the two json files by common field, with the desired format as above.

---

```
$json1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('json1.json'),true);
$json2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('json2.json'),true);

$json1['Common Field'] = $json2;

echo json_encode($json1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

this just outputs each entry from /`json1.json` as:

```
"0": { "Zipcode": "20101", "City": "", "Primary State": "Virginia", "Common Field": "49530", "County": "Loudoun" }
```

Comment: `$array1['Common Field'] = $array2;`?

Answer (score 1):

Decode the arrays and make the first associative with common field.
Then loop second array and add the subarray to the first array.

This will work on larger arrays than your sample given it has the same structure.

```
$json1 = '[{
   "Zipcode":"22581",
   "City":"",
   "Primary State":"Maryland",
   "Common Field":"49969",
   "County":"Something"
},{
   "Zipcode":"11111",
   "City":"",
   "Primary State":"Maryland",
   "Common Field":"11111",
   "County":"Something"
}]';

$json2 = '[{
    "Common Field":"49969",
    "Option 1":"Y",
    "Option 2":"",
    "Option 3":""
},{
    "Common Field":"11111",
    "Option 1":"Y",
    "Option 2":"",
    "Option 3":""
}]';

$arr1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$arr1 = array_column($arr1, null, "Common Field");

foreach($arr2 as $field){
    $arr1[$field["Common Field"]]["Common Field"] = $field;
}

var_dump($arr1);
```

Optionally you can use array_values to reset the keys to indexed type again.

Example output:

```
array(2) {
  [49969]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Zipcode"]=>
    string(5) "22581"
    ["City"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Primary State"]=>
    string(8) "Maryland"
    ["Common Field"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["Common Field"]=>
      string(5) "49969"
      ["Option 1"]=>
      string(1) "Y"
      ["Option 2"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["Option 3"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["County"]=>
    string(9) "Something"
  }
  [11111]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Zipcode"]=>
    string(5) "11111"
    ["City"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Primary State"]=>
    string(8) "Maryland"
    ["Common Field"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["Common Field"]=>
      string(5) "11111"
      ["Option 1"]=>
      string(1) "Y"
      ["Option 2"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["Option 3"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["County"]=>
    string(9) "Something"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/FQFBq

Comment: Overkill. No need for loop. See Charles' answer

Comment: @Onimusha if the array is only one item, yes. But I'm guessing adding two arrays with like the question asks is just an example that is easy to overview.

Comment: @Onimusha also, Charles "answer" has no explanation or anything that makes it an answer. So upvoting it would be contradictory to what SO wants.

Comment: But for anyone with basic knowledge of what they're asking for in the first place will know that `$abc['xyz'] = $cde` is creating a key with the requested array being the value so although explanations are very important to me also, here I think it's self explanatory.

Comment: Seeing the OP's comment on his answer, I now agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json1 = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('json1.json'));
$json2 = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('json2.json'));

$json1['Common Field'] = $json2;

echo json_encode($json1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "Zipcode": "22581",
    "City": "",
    "Primary State": "Maryland",
    "Common Field": {
        "Common Field": "49969",
        "Option 1": "Y",
        "Option 2": "",
        "Option 3": ""
    },
    "County": "Something"
}
```

Comment: This did not work; only added numbers i.e. { "0": { "Zipcode": "20101", "City": "", "Primary State": "Virginia", "Common Field": "49530", "County": "Loudoun" },

Comment: are you there now?

Answer (score 0):

```
$json1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('json1.json'),true);
$json2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('json2.json'),true);

$json1['Common Field'] = $json2;

echo json_encode($json1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

When you set second parameter as true the json convert to array but you set false which default is it then it convert to object.

Comment: Interesting, the answer with explanation is downvoted, and Charles without anything is upvoted.

Comment: I did not upvote or downvoite any yet; Charles answer did not work @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk` to get the desired result

```
$json1 = '{
 "Zipcode":"22581",
 "City":"",
 "Primary State":"Maryland",
 "Common Field":"49969",
 "County":"Something"
}';

$json2 = '{
  "Common Field":"49969",
  "Option 1":"Y",
  "Option 2":"",
  "Option 3":""
}';
$json1Array = json_decode($json1, true);
$json2Array = json_decode($json2, true);
array_walk($json1Array, function($value, $key) use (&$json1Array, $json2Array){
  $json1Array['Common Field'] = $json2Array;
});
$result = json_encode($json1Array);
```